# UISPlitViewController when have 2 ViewController in Master side does not work

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I use split view controller for my project. I have two master views which connected by segue. (they work well). I want when I click first master view only my second master view is shown(work well). and when I click the second one my detail view is effected(problem). I did that with one masterView but with two master views it does not work and my detail view is not effected.

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
RightViewController *rightViewController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
splitViewController.delegate = rightViewController;
UINavigationController *leftNavController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
LeftViewController *leftViewController = (LeftViewController *)[leftNavController topViewController];
```

I use this code when I have one viewcontroller after navigation controller in master side. but I dont know how change it when I have 2 view controllers after navigation controller in master side. I think I should change topViewController in last line but I dont know how change it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to happen, but in the viewDidLoad method of the second master controller, you can get a reference to the detail controller with self.splitViewController.viewControllers.lastObject (just like you do in the code you posted). With that reference, you can change whatever you want in the detail view controller.